# DTD character data validation error due to linebreak

Tags: dtd, sgml

I have the following `fake.dtd` file:

```xsl
<!ELEMENT outer - - (#PCDATA, foo, bar) >
<!ELEMENT foo - o (#PCDATA) >
<!ELEMENT bar - - (#PCDATA) >
```

And the following SGML document:

```xml
<!DOCTYPE outer SYSTEM "fake.dtd">
<OUTER>Document Title
    <FOO>1234
    <BAR>wxyz</BAR>
</OUTER>
```

I am getting a validation error using `nsgmls`:

> 4:19:E: character data is not allowed here

Note that putting `</OUTER>` on the same line as `</BAR>` solves the problem; the error refers to the line-break.

Is there a way to keep the SGML as is (because I already have thousands of documents like this), but change the DTD so that it validates?

Adding another `#PCDATA` to the end of the `outer` element seems silly because that would make characters other than newline legal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SGML Standard (ISO 8879:1986/A1:1988, 11.2.4) explicitly recommends to **not use** content models like `(#PCDATA, foo, bar)` (emphasis mine):

> NOTE - It is recommended that “`#PCDATA`” be used **only** when data characters are to be permitted anywhere in the content of the element; that is, in a content model where it is the sole token, or **where** `or` **is the only connector used in any model group**.

Despite mentioning `#PCDATA` only as the first token in the group, your `outer` element type still is declared to have *mixed content*, so data characters can occur anywhere: that's why the line break (aka a *"record end"*) after `</BAR>` is recognized as a *data character* instead of just a *separator* on the one hand, but there's no corresponding `#PCDATA` token to absorb it on the other hand, hence the error. (And only the omitted `</FOO>` end-tag circumvented the same error in the line before!)

---

The proper and common approach in this case would be to place the "Document Title" into an actual `title` element—for which one can allow omission of *both* the start- and end-tag:

```
<!ELEMENT outer - - (title, foo, bar) >
<!ELEMENT title o o (#PCDATA) >
```

Now

- your document instance is valid without modification,
- the `outer` content model still reflects the proper order of elements,
- the `outer` element has *element content* (**not** any longer *mixed content*),
- and the "Document Title" text ends up in its own `title` element, as it should.

(The same technique is used in several Standard DTDs, like the "General Document" example in annex E of the Standard.)

Answer (score 0):

Whitespace that looks innocuous is in fact significant character data, which results in an error. This is sometimes referred to as "pernicious mixed content". You have already hinted at a solution (allowing `#PCDATA` after the `bar` element):

```
<!ELEMENT outer - - (#PCDATA, foo, bar, #PCDATA) >
```

Another option is to allow `#PCDATA` and elements in any order (this is how mixed content must be declared in XML):

```
<!ELEMENT outer - - (#PCDATA|foo|bar)* >
```

I cannot think of anything else. It is not possible to restrict `#PCDATA` content to certain characters only.